# Global key is not restoring state sometimes of child widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Basically, in this example, I am using global key to restore value of by child,

This work,

But sometimes, it appears that the global key does not restore the value of the child items.

To make it clear, I have added a checkbox widget and a slider widget to the first and last pages of this code (green and red).

When I change the slider value on the first page and try to see it on the third page, it works fine.

Same thing if I change checkbox value (like true) on first page and then click on third page it shows mostly true, but sometimes does not.

I am unable to understand the reason behind this issue. Please refer to the following gif to better understand my question.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Global Key Example")),
      body: PageView.builder(
        itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          switch (index) {
            case 0:
              return Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: ActionPage(_key),
              );
              break;
            case 1:
              return Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text("Blank Page"),
              );
              break;
            case 2:
              return Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: ActionPage(_key),
              );
              break;
            default:
              throw "Not found";
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ActionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ActionPageState createState() => _ActionPageState();

  ActionPage(key) : super(key: key);
}

class _ActionPageState extends State<ActionPage> {
  bool _switchValue = false;
  double _sliderValue = 0.5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Switch(
          value: _switchValue,
          onChanged: (v) {
            setState(() => _switchValue = v);
          },
        ),
        Slider(
          value: _sliderValue,
          onChanged: (v) {
            setState(() => _sliderValue = v);
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What flutter version are you using?

Comment: i am using flutter 3.3.10,but this also arise on DartPad,as above image you see

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommened you to not use a `GlobalKey` here. Make sure to pass the needed data not the widget sate. If you take a look at the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) the following pitfalls are listed:

> GlobalKeys should not be re-created on every build. They should
> usually be long-lived objects owned by a State object, for example.
>
> Creating a new GlobalKey on every build will throw away the state of
> the subtree associated with the old key and create a new fresh subtree
> for the new key. Besides harming performance, this can also cause
> unexpected behavior in widgets in the subtree. For example, a
> GestureDetector in the subtree will be unable to track ongoing
> gestures since it will be recreated on each build.
>
> Instead, a good practice is to let a State object own the GlobalKey,
> and instantiate it outside the build method, such as in
> State.initState.

So you have to make sure that two widgets with the same key are never rendered on the screen at the same time. With a `PageView` this obviously can happen since you can display (eventhough there might be a transition state) two of your widgets with the same key at the same time. This can mess things up. Also they changed quite a bit in the past implementation wise if I recall correctly.

You should either pass the value directly to your widget or use something like an [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) to be safe.

Generally speaking I'd always try to avoid using `GlobalKeys` because they are quite complex and can have side effects which might not be always fully comprehensible. Also there are good alternatives.

Comment: ok,but can you explain what exactly reason for it,why screen older state lost on a randomly page change behaviors

Comment: As I said from my understanding it is because you display two widgets with the same key at the same time. This messes up the internal state of the key. GlobalKeys are complex and are reliant on some internal flutter state factors.